# How to get Openembedded to compile tar.gz files instead of tar.xz

Tags: bitbake, openembedded, opkg

I am trying to use openembedded and bitbake to compile programs for a processing unit. Once moved onto the processor, I will use opkg installed on the processor to install the programs. However, openembedded is compiling the program using tar.xz files when the version of opkg I am using requires tar.gz files.

I have looked into possible solutions to this problem. Unfortunately, for my project, updating opkg is not an option. I must find a way to have openembedded compile programs using tar.gz. Perhaps there is some setting I can change to have openembedded do this, or perhaps an older version of opendembedded uses tar.gz files instead?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

See package_ipk.bbclass:

```
OPKGBUILDCMD ??= "opkg-build -Z xz"
```

Set this in your distro config to be:

```
OPKGBUILDCMD = "opkg-build -Z gzip"
```